# MVC 4 Multiple HttpPost Single Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on MVC 4 Project. I have HomeController and Index Action. And Index action have 3 HttpPost method (Login, Register and LostPassword). 
But not working post method. Put breakpoint. But program not debug this points.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserLogin user)
{
   xxxxx;
   return Json();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UserRegister user)
{
   xxxxx;
   return Json();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LostPassword(UserProfile user)
{
   xxxxx;
   return Json();
}
```

How can i solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: How do you send the POST requests? Show us the views.

Comment: I send POST requests with JSON. (with button click event)

Comment: Can you show the code that generates and sends the JSON?